# Images as radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make images as radio buttons with jquery. The problem that I'm having is that is behaving like checkboxes rather than radio buttons. What I wanted to do is let the user makes only ONE checked! I tried using the `siblings()` function to uncheck the other elements but it's not working!

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="btn">
        <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
        <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="btn">
        <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
        <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="btn">
        <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
        <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="btn">
        <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
        <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
    </div>
</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('.btn').find('.checked').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.btn').find('.normal').show();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1pbvafoy/

Comment: Why not do that with just CSS? That saves you the job of writing any JS code for this purpose at all.

Comment: I suppose i would have to write way more with CSS. I mean, there's only 5 lines of JS code over there.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with just CSS, but here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj41cppy/) that uses some CSS. The JavaScript is shorter, and so it the HTML.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/prkqp26s/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
  $(this).parent('a').siblings().find('.btn .checked').hide();
  $(this).parent('a').siblings().find('.btn .normal').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <div class="btn">
    <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
    <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="btn">
    <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
    <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="btn">
    <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
    <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="btn">
    <img class="normal" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png" />
    <img class="checked" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</a>
```

1. Find the anchor first before looking for `.btn` since the anchor is not sibling of `.btn`

Comment: @Jonhz glad to help happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix https://jsfiddle.net/jvtppxyf/

you need to use parent()

```
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(this).find('img').toggle();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('.checked').hide();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('.normal').show();
    });
```